# sql server strip string

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, strip, postgresql

I have a table in SQL Server of strings that i need to inner join to another table that contains some similarity between substrings, here i have an example: Intel Atom CPU N450 @ 1.66GHz (INNER JOIN) Intel Atom N450@ 1.66GHz . I dont want use replace, i was thinking in something like using substring, pad, or something else. For example i wish to look for 'N450' on the other table. Could someone help me?

Comment: What's your logic to get N450 from "Intel Atom CPU N450 @ 1.66GHz".

Comment: I want to get Intel Atom N450@ 1.66GHz line when im looking through the substring 'N450' present in Intel Atom CPU N450 @ 1.66GHz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out CharIndex if you want to look for something in SQL Server.

Example:

```
Select * from YourTable where CharIndex('YourString', YourColumn) > 0
```

Relevant: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx